# Problem updating Item DynamoDB table on a Alexa Skill

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to update an item on a table, the skill has just one intent and it is supposed to update the item "status" to "on" or "off" depending on the conditional.

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk');
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamoDBTableName = "automation-test";
AWS.config.update({region: "ap-southeast-2"});
const tableName = "automation-test";
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();


const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'Welcome';
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};


const LivingRoomLightsIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LivingRoomLightsIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {

        const LightStatus = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.LightStatus.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].values[0].value.name;
        const deviceID = "livingRoomLights"

        if (LightStatus === "On") {

            const status = "true"
            const params = {
                TableName: tableName,
                Key: {
                  'deviceID' : deviceID,
                },
                UpdateExpression: 'set status = :s', 
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                  ':s' : status
                }
            };

        docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("Error", err);
            } else {
              console.log("Success", data);
            }
          });

        const speakOutput = `The living room light has been set to ${LightStatus}`;
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(speakOutput)
          .reprompt()
          .getResponse();

        }




         else if (LightStatus === "Off") {

            const status = "false"
            const params = {
                TableName: tableName,
                Key: {
                  'deviceID' : deviceID,
                },
                UpdateExpression: 'set status = :s', 
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                  ':s' : status
                }
            };

        docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("Error", err);
            } else {
              console.log("Success", data);
            }
          });

        const speakOutput = `The living room light has been set to ${LightStatus}`;
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(speakOutput)
          .reprompt()
          .getResponse();
           }
           } 
    };


const HelpIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'You can say hello to me! How can I help?';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const CancelAndStopIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && (Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent'
                || Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'Goodbye!';
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'SessionEndedRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        // Any cleanup logic goes here.
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
    }
};

// The intent reflector is used for interaction model testing and debugging.
// It will simply repeat the intent the user said. You can create custom handlers
// for your intents by defining them above, then also adding them to the request
// handler chain below.
const IntentReflectorHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const intentName = Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope);
        const speakOutput = `You just triggered ${intentName}`;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};

// Generic error handling to capture any syntax or routing errors. If you receive an error
// stating the request handler chain is not found, you have not implemented a handler for
// the intent being invoked or included it in the skill builder below.
const ErrorHandler = {
    canHandle() {
        return true;
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        console.log(`~~~~ Error handled: ${error.stack}`);
        const speakOutput = `Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again.`;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};

// The SkillBuilder acts as the entry point for your skill, routing all request and response
// payloads to the handlers above. Make sure any new handlers or interceptors you've
// defined are included below. The order matters - they're processed top to bottom.
exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
    .addRequestHandlers(
        LaunchRequestHandler,
        LivingRoomLightsIntentHandler,
        HelpIntentHandler,
        CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
        SessionEndedRequestHandler,
        IntentReflectorHandler, // make sure IntentReflectorHandler is last so it doesn't override your custom intent handlers
        ) 

        .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
  .withTableName(dynamoDBTableName)
  .withAutoCreateTable(true)
    .lambda();
```

Here is the log

> Unable to import module 'index': Errorat
>   Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)at Module.require
>   (module.js:596:17)at require (internal/module.js:11:18)at
>   Object. (/var/task/index.js:1:77)at Module._compile
>   (module.js:652:30)at Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:663:10)at Module.load (module.js:565:32)at tryModuleLoad
>   (module.js:505:12)at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)

Please help!

Comment: Please rule out all irrelevant code. E.g Is this an alexa issue or a dynamodb issue? You can work this out by running the code without being triggered from alexa. If you can reduce your code example to the few lines of code that cause the issue you'll get a better answer, See this:
https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Kindly show us your lambda function's file structure! I hope this is because of the improper folder structure in lambda

Comment: The file structure is the original one created by default when you create an hosted Alexa skill in the developer console.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDb uses 2 unique ID to detect a particular row. 
Make sure you are sending the information correctly. Then only your row will be detected and value be updated.